# Why is bcryptjs slower on AWS Lambda than in local docker?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, bcrypt

I have Lambda written in NodeJS. I noticed it takes several seconds to complete. I added logs and found that bcrypt is quite slow.

Packages:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
```

Source code:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

console.log("User was found"); // following part takes more than 1 second!
if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
    console.log("Password verified"); //
```

This is a log from AWS LogWatch:

```
2020-01-13T20:25:30.951 User was found
2020-01-13T20:25:32.670 Password verified
```

and

```
2020-01-13T20:31:20.192 User was found
2020-01-13T20:31:21.550 Password verified
```

So it takes 1.7 seconds. I ran the same code in docker on my machine

```
2020-01-13T20:09:48.109 User was found
2020-01-13T20:09:48.211 Password verified
```

Locally it takes just 120 ms. AWS uses NodeJS 10.x, local docker image is probably 8.x. I do not know how to tell docker to reflect changes in `packaged.yaml`.

Is this NodeJS regression? Or some issue on AWS configuration?

Comment: Wow, down vote? Why? I added code, a lot information ..

Comment: How does your Lambda runtime environment CPU compare to your Docker environment?

Comment: Could it be a difference in [bcrypt implementations](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js/issues/42)?

Comment: My laptop is quite powerful Dell XPS. Lambda - this is shared environment, not EC2 dedicated instance.

Comment: It seems like a war, people upvote and downvote ..

Comment: I have added version information: bcryptjs 2.4.3. So this is the same library on both sides.

Comment: AWS Lambda CPU is proportional to RAM, so choose the largest (3008) and re-test.

Comment: 21:00:13.570 User was found
21:00:15.388 Password verified
No improvement.

Comment: Are the lines of code in the Lambda function literally as you've provided? Or is there some missing handler code?

Comment: No, this is just a snippet. There is MongoDB fetching at the start and sending result afterwards. But the snippet is complete. It starts with the log and ends with the log.

Comment: When I run this inside a Lambda function handler on a 3008 MB RAM Lambda in us-east-1, the compareSync call consistently takes 90-100ms. With a 128 MB Lambda, it takes a little over 1s.

Comment: Are those tests ran in the cold-start of lambda? The first time Lambda executes a function it's significantly slow.

Comment: I tried to run it twice to avoid the child start

Comment: @jarmod please provide your solution as an answer, you were right. I was sleepy yesterday night and I modified differrent function with very similar name. I tried today again and it takes 110 ms with 3008 MB and 200 ms with 1024 MB.

Comment: @jarmod That is an interesting find and should be the answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encryption performance is typically CPU bound. AWS Lambda CPU is proportional to RAM, so you should choose the largest (3008 MB) and re-test.

When I run this inside a Lambda function handler on a 3008 MB RAM Lambda in us-east-1, the compareSync call consistently takes 90-100ms. With a 128 MB Lambda, it takes a little over 1s.

On a related note, it's helpful to understand that choosing the lowest (128 MB) RAM option, simply because it is cheaper per GB-s, is not always the best thing to do. While the highest RAM option (with proportionally higher CPU and network) is certainly more expensive per GB-s, it also completes Lambda functions a lot quicker. So, for example, you might be able to complete your task in 1/10th of the time at only 1.75x the cost. In a lot of situations, that can be very valuable.

There is a project that can help you tune price/performance for your Lambdas: [alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning](https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning)

Comment: And my findings: it takes 110 ms with 3008 MB and 200 ms with 1024 MB.

Comment: https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ - more context on bcrypt

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue , this is because you are using `bcryptjs` library try to use `bcrypt` is much much faster . `Bcryptjs` use plain javascipt thats why is too slow in the other hand `bcrypt` use c++ extensions

Comment: Thanks for tip, I will try it